ATOI in C messing with other strings in SERVER/CLIENT GMS application
We are trying to make a GMS server/client chat.
We are encountering an issue when using atoi on this part of the code
unserialize_tcp(buffer,&type, &grpname, &member_name, &received_addr, &received_port);
printf("1%s %s %s\n", grpname, member_name, received_addr);
addr = atoi(received_addr);
client.sin_addr.s_addr = addr;
client.sin_port = received_port;
printf("2%s %s \n", grpname, member_name);

and the output is this
as you can see the member name loses it's original value after we use atoi
Succesfully created RECEIVER WORKER and SOCKET WORKER 

Available options
     type 'exit' to close gms  
BEFORE
AFTER
BEFORE
New Client socket 4 stored at index 0
packet 0_omada_onoma_16777343_26385
1omada onoma 16777343
2omada @���x 
3omada @���x 
4omada @���x 
Group omada just got a new member @���x 
We didn't notify every member of the group  about the new member


this is the unserialize_tcp function
void unserialize_tcp(char* message, type_t *type, char** grpname, char** member_name, char** received_addr, int* received_port) {

    char msg[TCP_PACKET] = {'\0'};
    char *saveptr;
    char *ptr = message;
    char *delim = "_";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; ptr[i]; ptr[i] == '_' ? i++ : *ptr++);
    if (i != 4) {
        printf("Message corrupted\n");
        return;
    }
    strcpy(msg, message);
    *type = atoi(strtok_r(msg, delim, &saveptr));
    *grpname = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &saveptr);
    *member_name = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &saveptr);
    *received_addr = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &saveptr);
    *received_port = atoi(strtok_r(NULL, delim, &saveptr));
    

}


and this is the receive_worker thread that the problem with atoi originates

void *gms_receive_worker(void *args) {
  int i;
  char buffer[TCP_PACKET];
  char *grpname = (char*)calloc(16, sizeof(char));
  char* member_name = (char*)calloc(16, sizeof(char));
  type_t type ;
  char* received_addr = (char*)calloc(LENGTH_MSG, sizeof(char));
  char *msg;
  msg = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*TCP_PACKET);
  int received_port, addr;
  
  struct sockaddr_in client;
  while(!flag) {
    for (i=0; i< MAX_CLIENTS; i++) {
      memset(buffer, '\0',sizeof(buffer));
      if (recv(client_sockets[i], (char*)buffer, TCP_PACKET, MSG_WAITALL) < 0 ) {
            continue;
      }
      
      if(strlen(buffer) > 0) {
        printf("packet %s\n", buffer);
        unserialize_tcp(buffer,&type, &grpname, &member_name, &received_addr, &received_port);
        printf("1%s %s %s\n", grpname, member_name, received_addr);
        addr = atoi(received_addr);
        client.sin_addr.s_addr = addr;
        client.sin_port = received_port;
         printf("2%s %s \n", grpname, member_name);
        if (type == EXIT_TCP_SOCKET) {
          printf(BOLDRED"Client exited and the socket %d just closed\n"RESET, client_sockets[i]);
          client_sockets[i] = 0;
          continue;
        }
        else if (type == GROUP_JOIN) {
          printf("3%s %s \n", grpname, member_name);
          if (search_gms_list(list, grpname, member_name) != NULL) {
            msg = serialize_tcp(GROUP_REJECT_MEMBER, grpname, member_name, received_addr, received_port);
            if(send(client_sockets[i], (const char *)msg, TCP_PACKET, MSG_NOSIGNAL) < 0 ) {
                printf(BOLDRED"Failed inside group join\n"RESET);
                exit(1);
            }
            continue;
          }
           printf("4%s %s \n", grpname, member_name);
          printf(BOLDRED"Group %s just got a new member %s \n"RESET, grpname, member_name);
          
          add_gms_list(list, grpname, member_name, client, client_sockets[i]);
          msg = serialize_tcp(GROUP_SOMEONE_JOINED, grpname, member_name, received_addr, received_port);
            
          if (gms_sender_worker(grpname,member_name, msg) == 1) {
            printf(CYAN"We notified every member of the group %s about the new member\n"RESET, grpname);
            continue;
          }
          else{
            printf(CYAN"We didn't notify every member of the group %s about the new member\n"RESET, grpname);
            continue;
          }
            
        }
        else if (type == GROUP_LEAVE ) {
          if (search_gms_list(list, grpname, member_name) == NULL) {
            msg = serialize_tcp(LEAVE_FAILED, grpname, member_name, received_addr, received_port);
            if(send(client_sockets[i], (const char *)msg, TCP_PACKET, MSG_NOSIGNAL) < 0 ) {
                printf(BOLDRED"Failed inside group join\n"RESET);
                exit(1);
            }
            continue;
          }
          printf(BOLDRED"Group %s lost the member %s \n"RESET, grpname, member_name);

          delete_gms_list(list, grpname, member_name, client);
          msg = serialize_tcp(GROUP_SOMEONE_LEFT, grpname, member_name, received_addr, received_port);
            
          if (gms_sender_worker(grpname,member_name, msg) == 1) {
            printf(CYAN"We notified every member of the group %s about the member that left\n"RESET, grpname);
            continue;
          }
          else{
            printf(CYAN"We didn't notify every member of the group %s about the member that left\n"RESET, grpname);
            continue;
          }
        }
        else{
          printf(BOLDRED"You are not supposed to see this \n"RESET);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  free(grpname);
  free(member_name);
  free(received_addr);
  free(msg);
  

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}



when we put atoi in comments the member_name holds it's original value
The issue is very strange and we cannot find a solution.
Any idea is appreciated thanks!
What we expected:
Well we didn't expect for atoi to ruin the value of another string, we expected to see the same print statements. but we do not

Welcome to SO. Please try to create a minimal reproducible example{ (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-exampleI) and don't post a link to the output but paste the output into the question. Btw. I'm sure the problem occurs because member_name doesn't point to a valid address but it's impossible to say without having a complete example

this is the output
Available options
type 'exit' to close gms
BEFORE
AFTER
BEFORE
New Client socket 4 stored at index 0
packet 0_omada_onoma_16777343_26385
1omada onoma 16777343
2omada @���x
3omada @���x
4omada @���x
Group omada just got a new member @���x
We didn't notify every member of the group  about the new member

It means that you have UB elsewhere (not in the code provided)

atoi (family) isn't recommended to be used because it has no well-defined error handling. You should replace it with the equivalent strtol(str, 0, 10). Not necessarily the bug here, but always follow best practices. Additionally, strtol can provide more error results if/where the conversion failed.

I just updated the post can you guys take a look again?
we tried using strtol but the problem still occurs maybe we didn't use it correctly
cheers!

You are using the msg array in unserialize_tcp beyond its lifetime, resulting in UB. Specifically, the grpname, member_name and received_addr variables in gms_receive_worker contain invalid pointer values after the call to unserialize_tcp (and it also leaks memory).

You need to remove the msg string in unserialize tcp and use the message where msg goes

Here is your problem (one of them at any rate) in a dozen of lines:
int main()
{
    char* foo = malloc(100);
    bar(&foo);
}

void bar(char** arg)
{
   char example[] = "this is an example";
   *arg = strtok(example, " ");
}

Or, after manually inlining bar:
int main()
{
    char* foo = malloc(100);
    {
       char example[] = "this is an example";
       *foo = strtok(example, " ");
    }
}

You allocate a buffer in order to copy data to it. Not in order to immediately overwrite the only existing pointer to said buffer, losing the allocated memory forever, and creating a dangling pointer in the process (see this for more explanation).
What you need is actually this
int main()
{
    char* foo = malloc(100);
    bar(foo); // note no &
}

void bar(char* arg) // note one star
{
   char example[] = "this is an example";
   strcpy(arg, strtok(example, " ")); // note no `=`
}

